# Request keys from tableview and show them in Custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview, the tableview picks up data from a dictionary and shows it in the tableview. I also have a Custom tableview cell. The data which is displayed in the tableview, I need to show that in the custom tableview cell.
This is the code from my tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HistoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoryViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"PickupAddress"];
    return cell;
}
```

I need to show this data in my custom tableview cell. If it's not very clear, please ask and I will try to explain the best I can.

Comment: What is wrong with this code? it did not show cell, is it?

Comment: yes, i can't get this data to show in the custom cell

Comment: Have you checked if cell object is member of  HistoryTableViewCell

Comment: This line of code is what it's all about:  cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"PickupAddress"];

Comment: try to change owner:self to owner:nil and make sure dictionary exist

Answer (score 0):

You can override 'new' method in order to load cell from xib. Try this one

```
+(instancetype) new
{
    id cell = nil;
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        {
            cell = currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
    NSParameterAssert(cell);
    return cell;
}
```